# SQL Tables Join query

Tags: sql

I think this is a problem with my joins but I can't figure it out. I am trying to pull records for employee skills where they match the requirements for positions but also keep the records of skills that employee's have that are not required for their position. Here is the table for when I pull this employee's skills.

| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NHP-SAFE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 2.5 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | CWRIGHT |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 3.15 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NHP-ESD |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 2.3 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 3.14 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 3.2 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 2.10 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NHP-CLCK |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 2.7 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NHP-PATT |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NHP-BCC |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NHP-FOD |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 1.0 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 3.25 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 2.6 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QSL Log |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NHP-LDFC |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 2.11 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 2.2 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NHP-SA |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 2.4 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NHP-PSAF |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NHP-QUAL |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NHP-MSDC |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NH-HOUSE |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NHP-TRN |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 2.8 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 2.1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NH-TOUR |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 3.50 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | NHP-MFGP |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | QMS 3.67 |

Here is the table when I run my query with the position requirements.

| EmployeeID | Name | Dept | Job Title | Skill | Requirement | Descript | Date Acquired | Meets Requirement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | CWRIGHT | CWRIGHT | Falsification Training P-101, pg14, 18b | 2017-09-05 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | NHP-ESD | NHP-ESD | ESD Control | 2017-04-09 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 1.0 | QMS 1.0 | Quality Manual | 2017-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 2.10 | QMS 2.10 | Control of Solder and Flux | 2019-08-07 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 2.11 | QMS 2.11 | Hand Soldering and Rework SOP | 2019-08-08 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 2.2 | QMS 2.2 | Internal Audit | 2017-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | NULL | VISIONSC | NULL | NULL | 0 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 3.15 | QMS 3.15 | SDS | 2017-04-09 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 3.2 | QMS 3.2 | Training | 2020-01-20 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 3.25 | QMS 3.25 | MSD | 2017-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 3.50 | QMS 3.50 | Quality Systems Instructions | 2019-09-27 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 3.67 | QMS 3.67 | ESD Guidelines | 2017-04-09 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QSL Log | QSL Log | Inspection "Instruction" | 2019-09-27 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 2.3 | QMS 2.3 | Product Control | 2017-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 2.4 | QMS 2.4 | Improvement | 2017-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 2.5 | QMS 2.5 | Environment | 2020-01-20 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 2.6 | QMS 2.6 | Analysis | 2017-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 2.7 | QMS 2.7 | Control of M&M Equipment | 2017-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| A005122 | Adamus, Fred | 603 | Quality Technician | QMS 2.8 | QMS 2.8 | Inspection | 2017-06-21 00:00:00.000 | 1 |

Here is the SQL Query

```
SELECT 
        emp.emp_num AS 'EmployeeID'
        ,emp.name As 'Name'
        ,pos_det.dept           AS 'Dept'
        ,pos.job_title          AS 'Job Title'
        ,emp_skills.skill       AS 'Skill'
        ,rqmt.requirement       AS 'Requirement'
        ,skill.description      AS 'Descript'
        ,emp_skills.skill_date  AS 'Date Acquired'
        ,CASE WHEN rqmt.requirement = emp_skills.skill THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
        END                     AS 'Meets Requirement'

From    employee_mst AS emp 

LEFT JOIN emp_pos_mst AS emp_pos
    ON emp.emp_num = emp_pos.emp_num
LEFT JOIN position_mst AS pos
    ON emp_pos.job_id = pos.job_id
LEFT JOIN pos_rqmt_mst AS rqmt
    ON emp_pos.job_id = rqmt.job_id

LEFT JOIN empskill_mst AS emp_skills
    ON emp.emp_num = emp_skills.emp_num 
    AND emp_skills.skill = rqmt.requirement

LEFT JOIN pos_det_mst AS pos_det
    ON pos_det.job_id = emp_pos.job_id 
    AND pos_det.job_detail = emp_pos.job_detail

LEFT JOIN skill_mst AS skill
    ON skill.skill = emp_skills.skill


WHERE emp.term_date IS NULL
and emp.emp_num IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY emp.name
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jarlh that a simplified example would help us help you.

Reading your question a couple of times my best guess is you need to do one or more outer joins on your tables to arrive at the results *i think* you are aiming for.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp